# How to round float to one decimal point without using DecimalFormat class in java?

Tags: java

I was reading my old notes and found a question where a number with two decimal point is converted to a single decimal point. I looked around for answer and couldn't find it. I cannot keep it string as I have to return as a float and compare it. 
Math.round was rounding it bad and ceil and floor was giving me error. 
I came up with this solution.

```
public class floatRounding{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  //System.out.println(temperature((float)32.34));
 // System.out.println(temperature((float)32.35));
  if (temperature((float)32.34)<temperature((float)32.35)){
     System.out.println("Here"); 
  }
}

public static float temperature(float t){
  float newt;
  //newt=Math.round(t);

  String tem=String.format("%.1f",(t+.009));
  newt=Float.parseFloat(tem);
  System.out.println(newt);
  return newt;
}
}
```

Is there a better solution if I am not using decimal format like in this solution
[How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Thanks in advance. Please forgive if its a dumb question.

Comment: The question you linked to has more than 1 great answer...

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
     double x = 1.234;
     double y = Math.round(x * 10.0) / 10.0; // => 1.2
     System.out.println(y);
```

This rounds the decimal to the one decimal point, the code is much shorter. Hope this helps, if so accept the answer :)

Comment: But I was looking for 'float'. I know double makes much more sense.

Comment: Doesn't work, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421) for proof. @ranjutk `float` vs `double` is basically irrelevant here.

Comment: @EJP. Thanks! Makes sense.